# Add formatted text

Tags: java, swing, jtextcomponent

im stuck on a simple question, i want to display formatted text in a swing control and keep on adding new values into it, i don't want to use `.setText(.getText + text)` for personal reasons, (something like the append method for text area is what I am looking for) I've tried `JEditorpane, Textpane` but all of them do not have append method. Which swing control should I use?

Comment: What do you mean by *personal reason*?

Comment: .setText(.getText + text)' for personal reasons, yes you are right have to use Document

Comment: voting to close this question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While JEditorPane has no append method, you can certainly add text to its Document via its `insertString(...)` method, and I suggest that you look into doing this.

---

**Edit**
You ask:

> it worked it out but it seems it works like setText, all the previous data vanishes.. how do i keep the previous data ?

Are you correctly passing in the first parameter, the offset? This should be the length of the current Document.

Comment: it worked it out but it seems it works like setText, all the previous data vanishes.. how do i keep the previous data ?

Comment: @AjinkyaJumbad: are you correctly passing in the first parameter, the offset? This should be the length of the current Document.

Comment: sry, made a small silly mistake !! works now